# 'Open in new tab' in PPC & tracking

Tags: ppc

When a user clicks on an ad but they right click to open in new tab does that cost the advertiser as if the user would of left clicked.

I am new to all of this please handle me like that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the advertiser is charged if the ad is clicked or opened in a new tab either way the same URL is loading triggering the click. Though if you were to bookmark the ad or keep clicking or going back/forward Google recognizes this and the advertiser is not double charged

Comment: Thanks! Was sure they do protect themselves from all these problems....

Comment: You're welcome if you found this answer helpful feel free to check it off